# Links are coming as normal text without the link functionality in PDF using ABCPDF Library

Tags: pdf, hyperlink, anchor, abcpdf

I am using AddImageHtml function of ABCPDF Library for generating the pages with HTML content.
PDF generated text in anchor colour with underline but when I hover on it there is no link functionality.
I have a table of content along with headings in each page, whenever click on any of index content page should go to that 
page.

Added the following line immediate after create a doc object.

```
theDoc.HtmlOptions.AddLinks = true;
```

Added the table of content in `StringBuilder` and bind that `StringBuilder` object in `AddImageHtml` function like below

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append('<tr><td><a href='#About'>About</a></td><td> 1</td></tr>');

theDoc.AddImageHtml(@"<table width='100%'>"+sb.ToString()+"</table>");
```

In Another Page,

```
theDoc.AddImageHtml("<a name='#About'>About</a>");
```

Comment: Each time you call AddImageHTML it is adding the HTML individually. It doesn't remember the state of the page from one call to the next so there's no way for it to link the link to the anchor.. If you create an intermediate html file then you could use AddImageUrl to add HTML in one go in which case the link would work. What version of ABCpdf are you using?

Comment: Thanks, @PGTips for your response and I am using abcpdf.net 11

Comment: @PGTips - Tried passing HTML as a  string to AddImageUrl but this function is  expecting as URL, not an HTML File.

Comment: If you have a valid license, even the trial version, you can get support from: https://www.websupergoo.com/support.aspx